# BreezeJS and Entity Framework 6.0.1

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a Breeze Web API controller and I'm wondering if it is possible with the default MVC/Web API project template that comes with Visual Studio 2013.  Updating everything through the Nuget packet manager installs Entity Framework 6.0.1.  Attempting to installing Breeze after that results in an error as it attempts to install EF 5 as a dependency, which is not possible given the fact that other parts of the template depend on EF6.
Do we have to wait for a new version of Breeze that works with EF6?

Edit: I want to do this the "breeze way" using [BreezeController] and Odata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated 10/29/13

As of now, Breeze 1.4.5 has support for Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6. Please see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.

### Older post:

We don't yet support EF6 but it is coming ... soon...

Comment: do you can give any timeframe?

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to add that even without EF6.1, the MVC 5 updates released today with VS2013 also break breeze.  It's hard to separate the pieces to determine which new piece is responsible.  It could be MVC or the new odata.  In any case, we anxiously anticipate the new version.

Comment: same problem here. I hope there will be support for MVC5 soon!

Comment: I have the same problem EFContextProvider cannot be found

Answer (score 2):

There is a new package called Breeze.WebApi2 that is compatible with Web API2 and EntityFramework 6. It makes some of the existing Breeze packages obsolete. See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/start-nuget for details.